# How to do Link Aggregate / Load Balance with Ethernet and Wi-Fi

Tags: network, wifi, ethernet

Windows can run Connectify Dispatch (no longer available to download BTW), and both MacOS and Windows can run Speedify which proves that Link Aggregate with Ethernet and Wi-Fi is possible on macOS...too bad Speedify doesn't connect to the Internet directly...instead it connects to a VPN server. In theory we can create a virtual Ethernet port that is actually a Wi-Fi port and then use macOS' native Link Aggregation to combine bandwidth...Is there a software that does this?